# after upgrade 18.04 no gui available only tty

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub2

After upgrading my Ubuntu desktop from 17.10 to 18.04, everything went smooth until I restarted my PC.

The first suspicious thing I noticed was that it has the same grub with 17.10 - it selected the old grub from the menu (auto-select) and then showed me the boot screen. But afterwards instead of GUI I got terminal access (tty1) only.

How can I fix that? I tried running:

```
sudo update-grub
```

but with no luck and the initial grub is still the same. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: @KhaledE I didn't mate... I have just reinstalled it from scratch (the only drawback was to configure everything all over again)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I experienced the same problem and solved it by installing ubuntu desktop using this command`sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` 
**N.B** Your computer should be connected to the internet, for my case just plugged in an internet cable and used the commands above

Comment: I've just lost my GUI on 18.04 after last automated update and this solution has done the trick. Well done Onen.

Comment: This helped me fix my gui after I broke it due to purging some other packages

Comment: marking this as an answer ...

Comment: You saved me, i'm loving you rn.

Comment: Life...........saver......

Answer (score 6):

Try `startx`. I had the same problem but it worked for me. The solution is to start lightdm by yourself. The installation is indeed broken in some systems. `startx` command starts the GUI process for you.

Check status of display manager by executing - 
`sudo systemctl status lightdm`

Try restarting display manager by executing -
`sudo systemctl restart lightdm`

If this doesn't work, then you should try reinstalling Ubuntu.

Comment: Same problem here but no networking on tty. Selecting Enable Networking from the recovery menu does nothing so can’t install anything. Short of reinstalling, which is really not a good option, how does one move forward?

Comment: in case of you still have the GUI it works but when it broken you have to re-install the gui

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Try this it will work.

Comment: It's solved my problem on Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Solution 1: See if this works for you
First, open terminal by

```
 CTRL+ALT+F1
```

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo reboot
```

Solution 2: If the above doesn’t work, try this
First, open the terminal by

```
CTRL+ALT+F1
```

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Solution 3: If none of the above work for you, try this:
None of the above worked for me, however, so I upgraded my Ubuntu from 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04. All my previous files were preserved.
First, open the terminal by

```
 CTRL+ALT+F1
```

```
 
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: if you have no internet on the system then also this works sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

Answer (score 1):

I just used

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

And installed the nvidia graphics from terminal

It worked for me.

Restored the grub config to same file.  "quite splash"

Plus my ubuntu was 20.04 LTS